# Adding columns from sql table without cell values

Tags: sql, vb.net, forms, datagridview, copy

I am currently working in windows form applications vb.net for desktop 2013. I am trying to copy a row of values from a parent datagridview to a secondary datagridview with a button. I have a code to copy the row but i need to fill the secondary datagridview with the column information before I can make the copy happen. The first datagridview is set up through an sql connection. Is there a way to load ONLY the columns with no cell values into the secondary datagridview?

Here is my copy code for the button.

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
       Dim dr As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow
       For Each dr In Me.DataGridLine2.SelectedRows
          Me.DGVOrdered.Rows.Add(dr.Cells(0).Value, dr.Cells(1).Value,
              dr.Cells(2).Value)
       Next
        'IsDBNull(Me.DataGridLine2.Rows.Count)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the code to copy the columns only, however now my problem is I'm getting an error message about trying to copy bound data.

Here is the code I used for future reference of anyone trying to do this.

```
 dtselection.clear()
    For columnindex As Integer = 0 To DataGridLine2.Columns.Count - 1
        With dtselection.columns
            .Add(DataGridLine2.Columns(columnindex).Name, DataGridLine2.Columns(columnindex).ValueType)
        End With
    Next
    DGVOrdered.DataSource = dtselection
```

Comment: just for reference "dtselection" is a datatable, datagridline2 is my parent datagridview and "DGVOrdered" is my secondary datagridview, or the one that is getting copied into.